# IEnumerable<string> to SelectList, no value is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have something like the following in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = GetTheValues();
var selectList = new SelectList(list, "SelectedValue");
```

And even thought the selected value is defined, it is not being selected on the view.  I have this feeling I'm missing something here, so if anyone can put me out my misery!

I know I can use an annoymous type to supply the key and value, but I would rather not add the additional code if I didn't have to.

EDIT: This problem has been fixed by ASP.NET MVC RTM.

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 15):

If you're just trying to to map an `IEnumerable<string>` to `SelectList` you can do it inline like this:

```
new SelectList(MyIEnumerablesStrings.Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x,x)), "Key", "Value");
```

Comment: Instead of .Select(...), you can .ToDictionary(...)

Answer (score 14):

Try this instead:

```
IDictionary<string,string> list = GetTheValues();
var selectList = new SelectList(list, "Key", "Value", "SelectedValue");
```

SelectList (at least in Preview 5) is not clever enough to see that elements of IEnumerable are value type and so it should use the item for both value and text.  Instead it sets the value of each item to "null" or something like that.  That's why the selected value has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this: [ASP.NET MVC SelectList selectedValue Gotcha](http://replay.web.archive.org/20090628135923/http://blog.benhartonline.com/post/2008/11/24/ASPNET-MVC-SelectList-selectedValue-Gotcha.aspx)

This is as good explanation of what is going on as any.

Comment: FYI, the link is dead; looks like the domain expired.

Comment: Doesn't answer his question whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ViewBag.Items = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
                              {
                                  Text = x.ToString()
                              });
```

Comment: Give answer with some explanation