# Selected property on SelectListItem not being set by SelectList constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlistitem

I'm creating a `SelectList` to pass to a `Html.DropDownList`, but the correct value doesn't seem to be populating

```
var x = new SelectList(new[] { 
    new SelectListItem() { Value="1", Text="Vanilla"}, 
    new SelectListItem() { Value="2", Text="Chocolate"},
    new SelectListItem() { Value="3", Text="Strawberry"}
}, "Value", "Text", "2");
```

[`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.#ctor(System.Collections.IEnumerable,System.String,System.String,System.Object)) should take a constructor that takes in the `selectedValue`:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    object selectedValue
)
```

But this only sets the SelectedValue on the entire collection.  The individual `SelectListItems` haven't been set as `Selected`

[image: Inspector]

Do I need to iterate over them individually and set selected for each as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390874/1366033)?

Comment: Have you tried adding `, Selected=true` to the `SelectListItem` that you want selected?

Comment: @itsme86, this is a simplified example just for full transparency of the values going into the select list.  In my actual codebase those are being pulled in externally.  I could iterate through them and set the selected property manually, but it seems like passing in the selected value when creating the `SelectList` would do that automatically.  Further, if the selected value on item value isn't set, the dropdown doesn't populate with an initial value.

Comment: Creating a new identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one by using `new SelectList()` is just pointless extra overhead. And setting the `Selected` property is ignored when you binding to a property (its the value of the property that determines what is selected)

Comment: And your looking at the `items` property and you have not set the `Selected = true"` on any of those), not the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that is the result of that method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, ahh, okay, I was trying to be clever. Instead of passing the `SelectList` over a ViewModel, I created a `LookupProperty` class that just takes in a `Value` and a `SelectList`.  Then the property on my model has that class.  The problem is, when I create a `EditorFor(MyProp.Value)` the model binder works happily, but I don't get any of the data validation attributes on `MyProp`.  I was trying to use `EditorFor(MyProp)` which brings over the validation attributes. I added a ModelBinder to new up MyProp -> MyProp.Value, but then needed to render the class and point to the `Value`

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your last comment and what your trying to achieve. But for a bit more understanding of how to set the selected value, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685)

Comment: And if you have a look at the value of `x` then you will see that the 2nd `SelectListItem` has `Selected=true` (but as noted before, its ignored anyway unless your not binding to anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Selected` property **is** being set by the `SelectList` constructor. The image you have shown is for the `items` argument (i.e the collection of `SelectListItem` that you passing to the method), not the result of calling the method.

The constructor does not modify the collection passed to it, it creates a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and if you inspect the value of `var x`, then you will see that the 2nd `SelectListItem` (the one with `Value = "2"`) will have its `Selected` property set to `true`.

However, the purpose of the `SelectListItem` class is for use in one of the `HtmlHelper` methods that generates a `<select>` (`DropDownList()`, `DropDownListFor()`, `ListBox()` and `ListBoxFor()` methods) which accept an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as either the 1st or 2nd argument.

Unless you specifically not binding to a model property (e.g. `@Html.DropDownList("NotAModelProperty", Model.YourSelectList)`), then setting the `Selected` property is ignored because the method sets the selected option based on the value of the property your binding to (refer [How to set “selectedValue” in DropDownListFor Html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685) for more detail), therefore creating a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one by using `new SelectList(...)` is pointless extra overhead.

The reason for using the `SelectList` constructor is to create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from an existing collection of objects, for example

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options = new SelectList(db.Flavors, "ID", "Name")
```

which would get the records from the `Flavors` table, and set the `Value` based on its `ID` property, and the `Text` based on its `Name` property. It just provides an alternative to using (say)

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options = db.Flavors.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
    Text = x.Name
});
```