# Installing a modified version of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gac

I have made a relatively simple change to the MVC 1.0 source code to correct a bug in the DropDownList HtmlHelper ([discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614923/persisting-selected-value-in-mvc-dropdownlists)).

I was able to rebuild the MVC solution, ran all the tests, including the one I hadd added to show the bug I was fixing, and built a new DLL.

But how do I use that?

I tried moving the new MVC dll into the project and changing all the project references to point to it, but when I try to run the MVC website, it's throwing an exception saying there's a conflict between my version of MVC and the MVC in the GAC.

I tried to use gacutil.exe to remove the one from the GAC, but it says it can't do that because it would make another program (the Microsoft Installer?  fail.

What do I have to do to install my newly built version in place of the "official" version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove it from the GAC without uninstalling MVC (which includes the Visual Studio templates you probably need), you need to do this in the registry:

- Find registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Assemblies\Global and look for key starting with System.Web.Mvc – delete it

Now you should be able to use gacutil.exe to remove System.Web.Mvc from the GAC, and you should be able to use your version from your /bin folder.

Comment: Okay, that gets MVC out of the GAC and alleviates the conflict, but I still have parts of the code trying to load that version. Specifically, BuildManger.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath throws an exception saying that it can't "load MVC version 1.0.0.0, public token= ... the manifest definition does not match the assembly reference"
I've taken the assembly reference out of web.config and replaced it with a generic "add name="System.Web.Mvc" (without the details). Do I need an assembly re-direct, or something?  What else do I need to do to get it to accept the new version throughout?

Comment: Okay, I got it.  I had changed the assembly references in the root web.config, but missed the fact that the View folder has a web.config in it, and it had some fully-qualified references that I had to change. Once I did that, it worked.

Comment: I think you need the entries in web.config, in the system.web/compilation/assemblies section. Maybe try add that again. Have you strongly named the assmebly? Make sure your PublicKeyToken matches

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the version number when you compile the modified MVC framework?