# How can I override the Authorize attribute so I can put a breakpoint on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently doing the following to restrict access to a controller using windows authentication.

```
[Authorize(Users = @"DOMAIN\first.last")]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

}
```

This works fine currently but what I really want to do is:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"...")]
```

But whatever role I entered it didn't work.

I want to set a break-point so I can see which role the currently logged in user has, but I can't do that currently.

**Is it possible for me to inherit from Authorize and create my own filter attribute so I can put a break-point in it?**

I want to see what role the current user has, so I have to set a breakpoint at the correct spot.

I have this so far:

```
public class RoleFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{

}
```

Comment: ofcourse, you can always create one

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own (not inherit from AuthorizeAttribute) and just paste in the code that makes up [AuthorizeAttribute which you can get from GitHub](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs)

Or, you can simply point to the [MVC symbol server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050395/where-are-the-symbols-for-asp-net-mvc-4-0-rtm)

Comment: Looks like I still can't find what role I am in. maybe it doesn't expose that info?  https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L65