# need a value attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

return new SelectList(new[] { "Please choose an option." });

In the preceding statement, how can I add a value=string.empty for the text value above?

Thanks,
rodchar

The following is what works for me, however, is there a more consise way to write this?

```
return new SelectList(new[] { "Please choose." }
                .Select(a => new { value = "", text = a.ToString() }), "value", "text", "");
```

Comment: Check out this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work.

Comment: How do I accept this answer, if it's in a comment? Just pick "Answer Your Question" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General, I have been using something like this, you can customize this for your purpose (particularly the values part).

```
<% var values = Enumerable.Range(1,10); %> <!-- values from 1 to 10 -->

<%= Html.DropDownList("DropDownId",  
          values.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString()})) %>
```

For your case, I think you found the answer, just wanted to share how I use it.

Thanks