# Can't Get All Users in a Role using built in methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the default ASP identity modelin my MVC application.

as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399486/asp-net-mvc-3-dropdownlist-of-users), I want to get a list of users which are in a role:

```
var users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("employee");
```

However, this always throws

> The role 'employee' was not found.

Even though that role definitely does exist.

I can confirm this, as I am able to call :

```
User.IsInRole("employee")
```

For the current user, and this returns true.

I also noticed that these methods always return empty arrays:

```
var r = Roles.GetAllRoles();
var au = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

Why is this?

I know I can get the roles by directly making calls to the database context, but why can't I use the built in methods?

Comment: If you're using Identity framework, then you shouldn't be using the `Roles` and `Membership` objects.