# MVC .NET DropdownList selected value

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller

I have problem with dropdown list for my model. I cant set default selected value. Here is my code. 
Select list definition:

```
var productGroups = db.sl_GrupaKh.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(g => g.kh__Kontrahent.Any())
        .Select(n => new {n.grk_Id, n.grk_Nazwa })
        .OrderBy(n => n.grk_Nazwa).ToList();
        productGroups.Add(new { grk_Id = 0, grk_Nazwa = "(" + Resources.Resources.NoneLabel + ")" });
        productGroups.Add(new { grk_Id = -1, grk_Nazwa = "(" + Resources.Resources.AnyLabel + ")" });

        var selectedItem = productGroups.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.grk_Id==selected);
        SelectList selectList = new SelectList(productGroups,"grk_Id","grk_Nazwa",selected);
```

grk_Id - int type, grk_Nazwa-string type, selected - int type
I have watched that selected matches one of options value.

Now view code:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.customerMenu, Model.customerMenu,
new  {@class="myClass" })
```

And output:

```
<select class="dasdas" id="customerMenu" name="customerMenu">
<option value="2">Drogerie</option>
<option value="3">Fabryki</option>
<option value="4">Hurtownie</option>
<option value="5">Importerzy</option>
<option value="1">Podstawowa</option>
<option value="6">Sklepy</option>
<option value="0">(brak)</option>
<option value="-1">(dowolna)</option>
</select>
```

Im looking forward for any help. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SelectList` you can make use of `List<SelectListItem>` you only have to win from this, no more hardcoded strings, and you are sure that `Selected` item is `true` when you want.

```
var selectedItem = productGroups.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.grk_Id==selected);
List<SelectListItem> selectList = productGroups.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.grk_Nazwa,
            Value = c.grk_Id,
            Selected = selectedItem != null && selectedItem.grk_Id == c.grk_Id
        });
```

**Note:** if you can't  change `SelectList` try this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151351/3790486), this will help you to convert from `List<SelectListItem>` to `SelectList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is a mistake

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(productGroups,"grk_Id","grk_Nazwa",selected);
```

This

```
var selectedItem = productGroups.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.grk_Id==selected);
```

must be changed to this

```
var selectedItem = productGroups.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.grk_Id==selected).grk_Id;
```

Maybe with NullReferenceCheck.

Comment: @adricadar solution much better.

Comment: But i've used selectedItem  just to see if the selected parameter doesnt point to null while debbuging. As you can see: SelectList selectList = new SelectList(productGroups,"grk_Id","grk_Nazwa",selected); there is selected parameter not selectedItem