# DropDownList SelectList SelectedValue issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get this ASP.NET MVC SelectList to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work)

What the hell is it? Is there some kind of a bug in DropDownList of MVC3? 
SelectedValue doesn't show up as actually selected in the markup.

I am trying different approaches, nothing works.

```
public class SessionCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<SessionCategory> Categories
{
     get
      {
          var _dal = new DataLayer();
          return _dal.GetSesionCategories();
      }
}

@{
        var cats = Infrastructure.ViewModels.Session.Categories;
        var sl = new SelectList(cats, "Id", "Name",2);
}
@Html.DropDownList("categories", sl);
```

Comment: Can you confirm the cats var actually has categories in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to make the selected value a string. There's also some value in using extension methods as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work).

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var cats = _dal.GetSesionCategories();
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        // Preselect the category with id 2
        CategoryId = 2,

        // Ensure that cats has an item with id = 2
        Categories = cats.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.CategoryId,
    new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text")
)
```