# How to select an item from DropDownListFor list? (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm populating a drop down list using this code (and it works fine):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select a Country")
```

Sometimes, this view also gets data of a pre-selected country, so I want to select that country.

I tried:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text", "United States"), "Please Select a Country")
```

But this didn't work. I also tried the value of the item, and no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to access / modify that element after creation? (using C# not javascript)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work

Comment: I can't find a clear answer there, can you direct me maybe to a specific place? I would rather avoid functions for this if possible.

Comment: I got it to work when the model contains the value of the selected item, it works.
that is when:

    x.SelectedCountry

has data (the value, not the text), it works. (with the same code as before)

Comment: can you post your `ActionResult` that is responsible for generating the said view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 properties in the `Model.Countries` list: the `Text` and the `Value`. So if you want to preselect a given item in the dropdown you should use the value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedCountry, 
    new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text", "us"), 
    "Please Select a Country"
)
```

which assumes that in Model.Countries you have an item with `Value="us"`.

As an alternative you could do this inside the controller action that is returning the view:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Countries = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "fr", Text = "France" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "uk", Text = "United Kingdom" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "us", Text = "United States" },
    };
    model.SelectedCountry = "us";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view you could simply:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedCountry, 
    Model.Countries, 
    "Please Select a Country"
)
```

which will preselect the element with `Value="us"` (the third one in my example).