# ASP MVC3 - Drop down list not setting correct default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, html-select

Below is the `Edit` method from my controller. Everything works fine, however the current value for the agent in the `FixedOrVariable` drop down is not being set as the default value. I can edit this value properly, however.

The field `FixedOrVariable` is a one character field in the model. It's values are either `F` or `V` (always upper case).

Here is the controller method

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var banklistagentid = db.BankListAgentId.Find(id);
        ViewBag.BankID = new SelectList(db.BankListMaster, "ID", "BankName", banklistagentid.BankID);

        SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NA", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "US", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" });
        ViewBag.StateCodeList = tmpList;

        var fixedOrVariable = new[] {new {Text = "Fixed", Value = "F"}, new {Text = "Variable", Value = "V"}};
        ViewBag.FixedOrVariable = new SelectList(fixedOrVariable, "Value", "Text", banklistagentid.FixedOrVariable);

        return View(banklistagentid);
    }
```

And here is the code from the view

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FixedOrVariable, (SelectList)ViewBag.FixedOrVariable)
    </div>
```

Comment: Please check few answers about the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work/11705380#11705380).

Comment: Are your dropdown item display correctly?

Comment: @ararog: There is no need to override the `ToString` method, should be a much easier solution.

Comment: @IswantoSan: Yes the dropdown items are displaying correctly. Everything works fine except the default value isn't loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the single biggest mistake I've seen people make with Dropdowns in MVC.  You cannot name your list of choices the same as your selected item variable.

Change it to `ViewBag.FixedOrVariableList`