# What is the SelectList class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I'm trying to understand c# ASP.NET MVC4 and keep coming across `SelectList`. I can't seem to find an explanation of what it is, other that this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Can anyone give a simple explanation of it, and show how to use it?

Comment: http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/views/asp-net-mvc-select-list-example

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work for some examples.

Comment: This is a very pertinent question for ASP.NET MVC.  'What's this thing in c#'?  It's not asking to find a tool, library, or favourite off-site resource.  I had the same question and found the answers here very useful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple code that I used for dropdownlist in asp.net mvc:

In `Controller`:

```
   List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
   dropdownItems.AddRange(new[]{
                            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option One", Value = "1" },
                            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option Two", Value = "2" },
                            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option Three", Value = "3" }});
   ViewData.Add("DropDownItems", dropdownItems);
```

And, in `cshtml` view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Types", ViewData["DropDownItems"] as List<SelectListItem>)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Types)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that dropdownItems is much the same as an object of type SelectList? Also, most of the answers & comments dont actually mention selectList class - does this mean that it is not used much and I normally you would just use a List of selectListItem?

Comment: Yes, `SelectListItem` is type of `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`.

Answer (score 3):

*SelectList* class which contains the Key, Value pair with the Selected item to True.

For Example,

```
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = xElement.Element("text").Value,
                    Value = xElement.Element("value").Value
                });

var selected = listItems.Where(x => x.Value == "Test1").First();
selected.Selected = true;
```

This sample which helps to get the selected value in *dropdownlist*.

Answer (score 1):

Working with drop-down lists in ASP.NET MVC has some confusing aspects, it's the reason that you find some classes that help developers to work with this prevalent object.

There is a great blog-post which I think describes SelectList clearly.

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx