# DropDownList from Database using a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app which allows to create users which have a role. There's two roles : Administrator and User. When a registration comes, the user can choose thanks to a dropdown list the role of the new user. So here's what I've done so far.

My UserViewModel :

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="Username : ")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=6)]
    [Display(Name = "Password : ")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

And my HttpGet Method :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        context = new MainDatabaseEntities();
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(context.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDesc");
        return View();
    }
```

From here, I have no idea what I should do. Is my ViewModel good enough to do what I want (create and update an user)? How should I use my ViewBag.Roles into my Registration View?

Any help guys? I would appreciate it very much !

Comment: Go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/nerddinner/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes

Comment: This could prove very helpful for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Roles )
```

You should have a RoleId in your model to save the selected item in.

Comment: Yes indeed, through the Role object, I can get the RoleId and it works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles")
```

It will create the DropDownList for your ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly convert your ViewBag items to an expected type `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)`, as `ViewBag is a dynamic type`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId,((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles))
```

Comment: Don't just post code here, explain it so future users can understand it better

Comment: @FabioAntunes, added explanation

Answer (score 0):

First look, it is showing you are trying to register the account. For that follow step by step procedure:

Register http get method add following line

ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");

Then HttpPost methods add following line:

ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");

In the register view add following line:

@Html.DropDownList("UserRoles", (SelectList)ViewBag.Name, " ")

I hope this will work.