# How to set the default value for Html.DropDownListFor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

i have following code :
**controller method**:

```
 public ActionResult Register(int? registrationTypeId)
        {
            IEnumerable<AccountType> accountTypes = new List<AccountType>
            {
                new AccountType
                {
                    AccountTypeId = 1,
                    AccountTypeName = "Red"
                },
                new AccountType
                {
                    AccountTypeId = 2,
                    AccountTypeName = "Blue"
                }
            };
           // I want to select account type on registrationTypeId
            ViewBag.AccountTypes = accountTypes;
            return View();
      }
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.AccountType,
         new SelectList(ViewBag.AccountTypes, "AccountTypeId", "AccountTypeName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    { 
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Account Type")]
        public int AccountType { get; set; 
    }
```

As you can see **registrationTypeId** in controller , i want to set the type on its bases if it is not **null** ,otherwise set to red. I have tried a alot but nothing worked for me. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get this ASP.NET MVC SelectList to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781987/how-can-i-get-this-asp-net-mvc-selectlist-to-work)

Comment: set AccountType to set the default

Comment: i have added model @CodeCaster

Comment: please guide me how ? @MattBodily

Comment: What do you mean by default?  Do you mean you want to set the value?  Or do you mean you want it to display something when there is nothing selected (ie.. "Select a value" or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you don't pass your list through the view bag.  have seen too many questions where that has caused major issues.  add this to your model

```
public List<SelectListItem> AccountTypes { get; set; }
```

in your controller in the get method set your default and set your list

```
Model.AccountType = 1;  // change the one to your default value
Model.AccountTypes = accountTypes;  //instead of ViewBag.AccountTypes = accountTypes;
```

then on your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountType, Model.AccountTypes)
```

setting AccountType before passing the model to the view will set the default and the selected value on the view will be passed back in that same value.

Comment: Why are lists passed to the view in the ViewBag in examples and in the out of the box project?

Comment: my guess is it is a quick and dirty way to get it to work.  passing the list through the model is much more stable and reliable.

Comment: Microsoft's examples are famous for not being very industry-proof and for often showing "worst practices" unfortunately... because they are trying to market the idea of "easy to code" so they want it to look as simple as possible on their website

Answer (score 0):

## The Wrong Way To Do This

```
var accountTypes = new SelectList(accountTypes, "AccountTypeId", "AccountTypeName");

foreach(var item in accountList)
    if (item.AccountTypeId == registrationTypeId)
        item.Selected = true;

ViewBag.AccountTypes = accountTypes;
```

In view,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.AccountType, (SelectList)ViewBag.AccountTypes)
```

Comment: You do not (and should not) do this. Setting the `item.Selected` property is ignored by the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` so its pointless. If the value of `AccountType` matches the value of one of the options, then that option will be selected.

Comment: Didn't realise, never actually done it like this before.

Comment: I'll leave it up, your explanation might help people.