# How to set default category in a list ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I Just want to know how i can set a deafault category in my project .

Here is the Controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var ii = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        ViewBag.User_ID = ii;
        ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Category_id", "Category_name");
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <h4>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })</h4>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Category_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How to make a specific category id or name as default category in the list . Thanks

Comment: you might find this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/782030/28004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your view is strongly typed to a view model which has a `Category_id` property. What you can do is, create a object of your view model in the GET action, set the value of `Category_id` property to the CategoryId you want and Use the `DropDownListFor` helper in your view

So in your GET action,

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Category_id", "Category_name");    
var vm = new YourViewModel();
vm.CategoryId=3;         
return View(vm);
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to your view model

```
@model YourViewModel 
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Category_id, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList,
                                                         new { @class = "form-control" })
```