# Add an additional field to register form in mvc5 c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

So I linked my MVC application to an existing database and I've been trying to add the additional registration fields based on my existing database AspNetUsers table.

I need for the registration page to include a dropdown list containing Company names. I've added this field to the RegisterViewModel and added the SelectList to the AccountController and Register view but application keeps breaking.

Any help regarding how to achieve this will be appreciated.

AccountController:

```
        PosworxDBEntities db = new PosworxDBEntities();
        PosworxWebEntities db_ = new PosworxWebEntities();
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db_.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerName");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            AspNetUser users = new AspNetUser(); 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db_.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", users.Id);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
```

AccountViewModel : RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
```

The View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerID)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/782030/3378621 I think you need to fill your selectlist with a list and not a table.

Comment: customerID in the aspNetUsers table is a foreign key from Customers table though, so it will retrieve the required list if I'm not mistaken

Comment: The `SelectList` needs `SelectListItems` to populate the dropdown. Im not sure you can input the db table `db_.Customers` like that.

Comment: "application keeps breaking" do you see any errors?

Comment: It's throwing a metadata exception : Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'PosworxWebModel.FK_Support_Support' was not loaded because the type 'PosworxWebModel.Support' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'UserID' does not exist on the type '_PosWorx.Models.Support'.