# ASP MVC won't render selected value for a Select List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can only get the selected value to be selected on an MVC view when I use the ViewData object.  If I try to bind directly to a property on my model which returns an Ienumerable it won't render the Selected tag into the html.

I am at a loss on this one.

Note:  I do pass a strongly typed value to the View so my orginal binding was Model.Statuses where statuses is a property on my strongly typed model.

Comment: Can you show some code so we can see what you are doing? :)

Comment: this has been asked :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222531/ienumerablestring-to-selectlist-no-value-is-selected/566492#566492

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. It's currently assigned to me, in fact. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your template you are probably doing something like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("htmlName", Model.SomeIEnumerable) %>
```

And you need to make it a SelectList sort of like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("htmlName", new SelectList(Model.SomeIEnumerable, "valueProperty", "textProperty")) %>
```